# Determining distributions/relations between two random variables

Tags: probability, statistics

"A manufacturer of a certain product has a label weight for this product of 20.4 grams. The weight of the products are given by $X \sim N(21.37,0.16)$.

Suppose 15 of these products are selected randomly and weighed. Let Y be the number of these products that weigh less than $20.857$ grams. Find $P(Y \leq 2)$"

My first thought was that Y must be binomialy distributed, each element having the option of being either over or under the weight $20.857$. The number of trials is $n = 15$, the probability  $p = P(X \leq 20.857)$. Thus we seek to determine binomialcdf(n,p,k) = binomialcdf(15,p,2). To determine $p$ we calculate Normalcdf(a,b,$\mu$,$\sigma$) = Normalcdf(0,20.857,21.37,0.4) $\approx 0.099833$.

Thus we get binomialcdf(15,p,2) $\approx 0.81657$. The answer in the textbook is $0.8159$, frustratingly close. Is my entire line of reasoning wrong, or did I miss something in my calculations? (Note that in my actual caculations, I did not 'round' anything as I went along)

Comment: I suspect that $a=-\infty$ and $b=20.857$ here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution of the textbook is based on rounding:

$\text{Normalcdf}(0,20.857,21.37,0.4)\approx 0.099833 \approx 0.1$

$P(Y\leq 2)=P(Y=0)+P(Y=1)+P(Y=2)$

$=\binom{15}{0} \cdot 0.1^0\cdot 0.9^{15}+\binom{15}{1} \cdot 0.1^1\cdot 0.9^{14}+\binom{15}{2} \cdot 0.1^2\cdot 0.9^{13}=0.8159$

Rounded up to 2 decimal places.

Comment: Aah, I see! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome.